# The Copenhagen Interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, history, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse, specific-reference

What are the actual papers in which Bohr, Born, and others proposed the Copenhagen interpretation? I know that Bohr himself didn't use the term, but I assume that he outlined the way of understanding QM in some of his papers or books. What are the titles of those pioneering papers or books?

Comment: Nobody ever proposed a "Copenhagen interpretation" (BTW this is stated at the very beginning of the corresponding Wikipedia entry, please do some research before posting here), so there are no such historical papers. Bohr's views, notably, are notoriously very difficult to grasp. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-copenhagen/